# Typing Text into the Tkinter Canvas Widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I need to allow the users to type text into the Canvas Widget, making the canvas update as the user types new text.

Here's what I have tried so far, but am not getting it to work.

First I have a `mouseDown` method which is bound to Button-1 event

```
widget.bind(self.canvas, "<Button-1>", self.mouseDown)
```

This `mouseDown` method returns the `startx, starty` positions to my method `drawText`

```
def drawText(self, x, y, fg):
    self.currentObject = self.canvas.create_text(x,y,fill=fg,text=self.typedtext)
```

I also have a global binding on the canvas widget to capture any key press like this:

```
Widget.bind(self.canvas, "<Any KeyPress>", self.currentTypedText)

def currentTypedText(self, event):
    self.typedtext = str(event.keysym)
    self.drawText(self, self.startx, self.starty,self.foreground)
```

However there's no error and nothing gets printed on the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is pretty complex and will require quite a bit of code to get working nicely.  You will need to handle click events, keypress events, special keypress events (such as "Shift" and "Ctrl"), "Backspace" and delete events, and a lot more.

Nevertheless, first is first and that is getting text to appear in the canvas as a user types.  Now, since I don't have your full script, I can't really work with your stuff as is.  However, I went and made my own little app that does exactly what you want.  Hopefully, it will shine some light on where to go:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        # self.x and self.y are the current mouse position
        # They are set to None here because nobody has clicked anywhere yet.
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.makeCanvas()
        self.bind("<Any KeyPress>", lambda event: self.drawText(event.keysym))

    def makeCanvas(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.mouseDown)

    def mouseDown(self, event):
        # Set self.x and self.y to the current mouse position
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

    def drawText(self, newkey):
        # The if statement makes sure we have clicked somewhere.
        if None not in {self.x, self.y}:
            self.canvas.create_text(self.x, self.y, text=newkey)
            # I set x to increase by 5 each time (it looked the nicest).
            # 4 smashed the letters and 6 left gaps.
            self.x += 5

App().mainloop()
```

Once you click somewhere in the canvas and start typing, you will see text appear.  Note however that I have not enabled this to handle deletion of text (that is a little tricky and beyond the scope of your question).

Comment: I realize it's been a few years since this answer was made. Regardless, I want to point out the fact that you don't have to create a new text item for every keystroke. Canvas text items are editable. For an implementation, see http://effbot.org/zone/editing-canvas-text-items.htm